# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in localhost using odoo with ajax method post Api

Tags: json, ajax, api, cors, odoo

This is my code :

```
 function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}

xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1/transactions';
xml.open('post',url);   

$.ajax({
        url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1/transactions",

        type: "post",
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        Accept : "application/json",
         xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    contentType:  "application/json; charset=utf-8",


    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth("SB-Mid-server-aaaa:","")); 

    },

        data: '{"transaction_details":{"order_id":"ORDER-109","gross_amount":75000},"credit_card":{"secure":true},"item_details":[{"id":"ITEM1","price":10000,"quantity":5,"name":"Midtrans wwwwww"},{"id":"ITEM2","price":5000,"quantity":5,"name":"Midtrans wwdwdwdwd"}],"customer_details":{"first_name":"TEST","last_name":"MIDTRANSER","email":"noreply@example.com","phone":"+628123456","billing_address":{"first_name":"TEST","last_name":"MIDTRANSER","email":"noreply@example.com","phone":"081 2233 44-55","address":"Sudirman","city":"Jakarta","postal_code":"12190","country_code":"IDN"},"shipping_address":{"first_name":"TEST","last_name":"MIDTRANSER","email":"noreply@example.com","phone":"0812345678910","address":"Sudirman","city":"Jakarta","postal_code":"12190","country_code":"IDN"}}}',
         success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        snap.pay(data.token);
        alert("bisa");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
      alert("error");

    }


    });
```

I use cors proxy but still have the error `The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'`. Here is the full error message:

> web.assets_common.js:1209 Failed to load
>   https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1/transactions:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'http://10.0.75.1:8069' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHp26.png)
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

[this is error picture,why my method option i already send method post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHp26.png)

Comment: Add capital letters and format the error message in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred when you have multiples data bases, you have to specify what data base are you using, because your Ajax method doesn't know which Odoo controller of what data base calls, you can filter one data base using this parameter in your configuration file `dbfilter='database_name'` or in your command line: `--db-filter database_name`.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.